# Single Shared Transition Animation for RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, material-design, shared-element-transition

I only want to use `Shared Transition Animation` for a image. When I click the cardview, image inside `cardview` will be at top of the new activity. Layouts are okey. Having trouble about to implement.
*(I also set transitionName for detail activity image)*

**RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    String urlExtension = "http://192.168.1.110/myapp/public/images";
    Glide.with(context).load(urlExtension+searchList.get(position).getSearch_image()).into(holder.item_search_image);
    holder.item_search_text.setText(searchList.get(position).getSearch_city());

    holder.item_search_image.setTransitionName("searchToItemTransition");

    final ActivityOptionsCompat optionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
            (Activity) context,
            holder.item_search_image,
            holder.item_search_image.getTransitionName());


    holder.item_search_cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Page_ItemCity.class);
            intent.putExtra("intent_city_name",searchList.get(position).getSearch_city());
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent, optionsCompat.toBundle());
        }
    });
}
```

I get error about casting. I can do it as pairs, but I only want to make it single. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you pass the context to your Adapter constructor?

Comment: I set `Context context` at global of `Adapter`

I pass `getApplicationContext` to adapter

Comment: It's in the `Activity`? Pass `this` instead of `getApplicationContext` then the casting should work.